# Disregard a cell in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to have a VBA macro loop through a range of cells and populate a User Form Listbox with each unique value that it finds.  The range of values is in column "L".  I have that figured out, however the stipulation I'm having trouble coding is that I also need it to look at the value in Column "D" as well, and to NOT add the value in column "L" to the Listbox if it finds a value in Column "D".

I've included a screenshot of what the worksheet would look like and the desired output would be.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  
Dim Dict As Object
Dim Key As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Relay As Range


With Sheets("Score Sheet")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each Relay In .Range("L2:L" & LastRow)
    If IsEmpty(Range("D" & Relay).Value) = True Then
            If Relay.Value <> "" Then
            If Not Dict.exists(Relay.Value) Then
                Dict.Add Relay.Value, 1
                
        End If
        End If
        End If
       Next Relay
End With

For Each Key In Dict.keys
    lstRelayNumber.AddItem Key
Next Key

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `If Len(.Range("D" & Relay.Row).Value) = 0 Then`

Comment: I had a feeling it was something simple, thanks so much I really appreciate it!  That works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Relay As Range, vL, vD
    
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Sheets("Score Sheet")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each Relay In .Range("L2:L" & LastRow).Cells
           vL = Relay.Value                    'Column L value 
           vD = .Range("D" & Relay.Row).Value  'Column D value
           If Len(vL) > 0 and Len(vD) = 0 Then
               If Not Dict.exists(vL) Then
                   Dict.Add vL, 1
                   lstRelayNumber.AddItem vL 'can add to the list in this loop...
               End If
            End If
        Next Relay
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a significantly cleaner approach, thanks again for your help, I appreciate it!